# Why path with 2 words ("Start Menu") doesn`t work correctly in c++?

Tags: c++, windows

It doesn`t work because it could be `"Start menu"`, not `Start menu` . But `system("_path_"Start Menu"_path_")` gives an error (`system('_path_"Start Menu"_path_')` also gives an error). How to fix it?

Code:

`system("move C:\\Users\\%USERNAME%\\Downloads\\a.exe C:\\Users\\%USERNAME%\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup");`

Comment: You need to quote the path with spaces in it, then it works.

Comment: The syntax of the command is incorrect. it gives

Comment: You need double-quotes around the paths. And you need to *escape* the double-quotes since they are in a string.

Comment: I know, in python you could `system('_path_"Start Menu"_path')` but in c++ it gives error because it should be `system(" ")`, not `system(' ')`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude can you write please the whole code?

Comment: @fur1ous You need to escape the double quotes, just as you escaped the backslashes in the path (you could do the same in Python, incidentally): `\"`.

Comment: As any decent [book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), tutorial or class should have mentioned, you need to *escape* double quotes inside a string. As in `std::cout << "This strings contains \"double quotes\"\n";`

Comment: I am sorry, i am noob at this: so it could be `Windows\"Start Menu\"\nPrograms` ? @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: If you would write the command in a Windows command window, how would you place the quotes for the command to be correct? Do the same here in your program, but remember the *escapes* (backslashes).

Comment: You may want this: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/rename](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/rename)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
system("move \"<src_path>" \"<dest_path>\"");
```

Also, if you need escape a `"` characters inside of a path, use `\` to escape, but as far as I know, Windows would not allow you to name entities with particular set of special characters.

Comment: Great job on answering this question!

Comment: NTFS allows `"` characters in path and file names. Neither Windows' command prompt nor File Explorer allow you to create such files. The Windows API and the Native API, on the other hand, do.

Comment: @IInspectable I didn't know that, thank you!